# Input ao mudar de classe com JS não vai junto ao form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Olá, eu tenho basicamente um form dessa forma.

```
<form action="ok.php" name="s" method="POST">
<label id="flabel" class="UnlockWalletViaKeystoreFile__file-input">
<input type="file" id="finput" name="arquivo" required>Choose Keystore File</label>
</form>
```

Eu uso o JS para que quando houver uma modificação no input, ele mude a class do label e mostre um texto dessa forma abaixo.
OBS: Uso o JQuery.

```
<script>
$('#finput').change(function() {
document.getElementById("flabel").classList.add('UnlockWalletViaKeystoreFile__file-input--has-file');
document.getElementById("flabel").innerHTML = "Keystore File Set!";
});
</script>
```

No entanto, quando eu tento enviar o formulário, o input simplesmente não vai junto ao request. Ou seja, não é enviado junto ao formulário. Já tentei adicionar outros inputs sem mudar a classe. E sim, funciona.

Comment: Alterar innerHTML substitui todo o conteúdo do seu label, incluindo o input, pelo novo valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está substituindo o conteúdo do label, e isso está incluindo o input:

```
document.getElementById("flabel").innerHTML = "Keystore File Set!";
```

Sugiro retirar o input de dentro do label:

```
 <form action="ok.php" name="s" method="POST">
    <label id="flabel" class="UnlockWalletViaKeystoreFile__file-input">Choose Keystore File</label>
    <input type="file" id="finput" name="arquivo" required>
  </form>
```